# Using one mouseListener

Tags: java, swing, menu, jbutton, mouselistener

I am making a menu for a game with multiple JButtons, I created a new class for a mouseListener, and use mouseReleased to execute my code, then I add that class to my JButton l. So my question is if I want my second button to run some different code do I need to create a new class for it or is the a way I can do it in the Input class, where my code for my first button is.

```
    JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    play.setBounds(299, 80, 170, 70);
    play.addMouseListener(new Input());
    panel.add(play, null);
```

This is my code for my mouseListener.

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    JFrame gameWindow = new JFrame("");
    gameWindow.setSize(Frame.windowWidth, Frame.windowHight);
    gameWindow.add(new Draw());
    gameWindow.setVisible(true);
    gameWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Comment: why do you add a mouse listener on the button?

Comment: @FooBarUser What do you mean, what else was I supposed to do?

Comment: You can create another class that implements mouseListener or you can use getSource to evaluate who is the event owner, you also can add an argument to your Listener class to help the event to know what to do and there you would need 2 instances instead of 2 classes.

Comment: Commonly Buttons use action listeners instead of mouse listeners, what would happen if you press Enter with your keyboard? it will not trigger mouse released, but it triggers action as well as clicking.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {           
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Your Code Here     
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, but why should the OP use it...copy & paste code leads to many developers into trouble ;)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I went with porfiriopartida advice and use .getSource, it was easy to figure out and saves a bit of code.